# Replace blank with date

Tags: jmeter

```
String c = ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,P10D,)}
log.info("Today date " + "${c}")
vars.put("DATE_PLUS_10", "${c}")
System.out.println("${c}");   ---- This is printing 2007
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info('Response Initial: ' + response)
def request = response.replaceAll('""', ${DATE_PLUS_10})
log.info('Response Massaged: ' + request)
vars.put('request', request)
//vars.putObject('request', 'request');
System.out.println(${request});
```

I need to add 10 days to current date and replace the null value with DATE_PLUS_10

> 2020-02-29 20:20:15,548 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in
>   JSR223 script, RESPONSE_STORE javax.script.ScriptException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.$() is applicable
>   for argument types: (Script2$_run_closure1) values:
>   [Script2$_run_closure1@76fcaee5] Possible solutions:
>   is(java.lang.Object), any(), get(java.lang.String),
>   any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait()    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]   at
>   javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]

Can someone pls tell me what is the issue in the line :

```
def request = response.replaceAll('""', ${DATE_PLUS_10})
String c = ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,P10D,)} -
```

DATE_PLUS_10=2007 - this is what debug sampler displays..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `${}` syntax in JSR223 script,

You can add a PreProcessor [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters)

> Allows the user to specify values for User Variables specific to individual threads

Add a variable as `DATE_PLUS_10`  with value:

```
  ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,P10D,)}
```

Then use it in script

```
 String c = vars.get("DATE_PLUS_10");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global or user variable and after that you can write

```
def DATE_PLUS_10=vars.get("DATE_PLUS_10")
log.info(DATE_PLUS_10)
def response = "2020-05-01"//prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info('Response Initial: ' + response)
def request = response.replaceAll('""', DATE_PLUS_10)
log.info('Response Massaged: ' + request)
```

As mentioned in previous answer you can not use ${} inside JSR223 processor.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below this beanshell preprocessor.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
    import java.util.Date; 

    Date date = new Date(); 
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+10); 
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    // or: SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
    String formattedDate = df.format(date); 
    vars.put("FUTUREDATE",formattedDate);
```

And used the JSR post processor

```
def mydate =vars.get("FUTUREDATE");
log.info("my date" + mydate)
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info('Response Initial: ' + response)
def request = response.replaceAll('""', mydate)
log.info('Response Massaged: ' + request)
vars.put('request', request)
//vars.putObject('request', 'request');
System.out.println(${request});
```

Issue resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Deon't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into scripts, you can use "Parameters" section instead like:

[image]

or alternatively if you want "pure" Groovy code:

```
def newDate = new Date().plus(10).format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image]

More information:

- Groovy [Date.plus()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#plus(int)) function
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)